# No static method parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;

Tags: gson, jsonparser

I get gson 2.8.6 in my project,but still have the error
maybe I get low version in my project,but should't use the lastest?
and i try force gson version to 2.8.6,but it don't work

Comment: Can you please make sure your build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle) uses the correct version and the version is not overwritten by a dependency? Please try to reduce this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This makes it easier to troubleshoot, and often during the process of creating the example one notices the underlying issue.

Comment: I use this to make sure gson version is 2.8.6

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    }
}